# How to get class files or Dalvik byte code of standard java libraries that are used by Dalvik VM?

Tags: java, android, bytecode, dalvik, dex

I want to get the Dalvik bytecode for standard Java libraries, I mean, java libraries that are utilized by Android (e.g. java.util.* collections).

I need to get those class files because I want to analyze them, not all of them, but something like `java.util.*`, `java.lang.*`, etc.

However, when compiling any Android applications, no class files of those standard libraries would be generated, except for the application code and dependencies libraries.

So I'm wondering how to get the compiled class files (and its corespondent dex files when compiling in Dalvik VM)?

I tried to pull the standard Java libraries in an Android project, like get all the Java source code and add them as application code, OR put the `classes.jar` (`rt.jar`) in the libs folder, however, these two ways are not working because the source code  or jar file in project will be in conflict with the default compilation environment and so give out dreaded error `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

Any idea how to get what I want?

Comment: Your question needs more detail as I don't understand why you are looking for the collections class files, and Android already has the collection classes.

Comment: I'm not actually clear on what you are trying to do. Do you just want to look at the source for some of the core java libraries used by Android, or are you wanting to actually include these classes in your project? (and if so, why?)

Comment: @JesusFreke Not looking in the source. I need to include these classes in a project, so that I can analyze them (the byte code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sources and the binaries of the system libraries are available as part of the Android SDK. Just look into the install directory `platforms/android-{version}/android.jar` for the binaries and `sources/android-{version}` for the sources (if you installed it).

Comment: The `android.jar` does not contain the actual class file binaries.  If you examine the contents you'll see that all of the method implementations are stubs, and only for the public non-hidden code.  This jar file is just something for the SDK to compile+link against.

Comment: @Henry Thanks to your information, I finally get all the Dalvik bytecode for android.jar. I used `dx --core-library --dex --output="android2.apk" "android.jar" ` to first turn it into `apk` file, which can be extracted by `apktool`. Or the `android.jar` can be   turned into `.dex` format directly using `dx`. Then the dex file can be disassembled by `Dedexer` tool.